# How can I make python busy-wait for an exact duration?

Tags: python, time, sleep

More out of curiosity, I was wondering how might I make a python script sleep for `1 second` without using the `time` module?

Is there a computation that can be conducted in a while loop which takes a machine of `n` processing power a designated and indexable amount of time?

Comment: It's been a long time since you could get a reliable delay out of just trying to execute code that would take a certain time to complete. Computers don't work like that any more.

Comment: The processing time is depends on the machine you are working with and active processes on it. There is no fixed amount of time for an operation.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the helpful link – it does not, since I'm trying to explore a solution deliberately without the `time` module.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments for your second part of question:

> The processing time is depends on the **machine**(computer and its configuration) you are working with and **active processes** on it. There isnt fixed amount of time for an operation.
>
> It's been a long time since you could get a reliable delay out of just trying to execute code that would take a certain time to complete. Computers don't work like that any more.

But to answer your first question: you can use system calls and open a os process to sleep 1 second like:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["sleep", "1"])
```